# Finding an element in UI Test with only substring Xcode

Tags: xcode, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing, uiaccessibility

I have a web view in my app that I use for account creation (I didi not write and cannot change the associated web pages).

Normally, it is easy to click on any button/link but here the string of my "Create Account" button has an font awesome in its title with makes the recorder crash and the button cannot be programmatically called.

Here is what it prints in `app.webViews.allElementsBoundByIndex`:

```
Element subtree:
 →WebView, 0x1c03823c0, traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {736.0, 414.0}}
...
Link, 0x1c0384100, traits: 8590065666, {{242.0, 357.0}, {252.0, 44.0}}, label: 'create account '
```

As you can see, the font awesome turns into  `` which I cannot detect with something like:

```
webViews.staticTexts["create account "].tap()
```

**Questions**

1. How can I look into staticTexts with just a substring of the query (here is would be webViews.staticTexts["create acco"].tap() for example) ?
2. Is there a better way to find and click on this button and associated link ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use an `NSPredicate` to find static texts containing a partial word/phrase, using the [`containing(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielementquery/1500956-containing) method on `XCUIElementQuery`.

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "label CONTAINS 'create account'")
let app = XCUIApplication()
let createAccountText = app.webViews.links.containing(predicate)
createAccountText.tap()
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no shortcut for using `starts(with: Sequence)` on subscripts. Therefore, you should go through every text field and check if it's label starts with `create account`:

```
func testStartsWith() {
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    let staticTexts = app.webViews.staticTexts // or app.webViews.links
    for i in 0..<staticTexts.count {
        let text = staticTexts.element(boundBy: i)
        if text.label.starts(with: "create account") {
            text.tap()
            break
        }
    }
}
```

*Note:* Since you are using WebView, there are lot more `staticTexts` elements than there are `links` elements. According to printout you provided, your `create account ` view has link trait, so you should be able to use `app.webViews.links` for faster matching.